# Terminal command for infinite execution of application

Tags: mac, bash, terminal, infinite-loop

I tried almost every keyword on Google and still didn't came up with an answer. So hopefully one of you knows.

What is the terminal command keep a application running after it fails or stopped executing.

I tried this loop command in terminal:

```
bash -c 'while [ 0 ]; do COMMAND_HERE;done'
```

But it executes the commando immediately and not after the previous command failed or ended.
I want the command to only execute if the process ended.

I want to use the command for ffmpeg while broadcasting a live stream. Some times the connection fails or some other issues happen. When that happens ffmpeg stops executing (obviously), but i want it to retry the same command again and again after it.

How do you do that?

Ps. I already tried these keywords on Google (i don't know why i still havent found any close answer):

- mac execute command on fail
- mac execute command synchronously
- mac bash re execture terminal
- mac loop command
- mac re-run application if stops
- mac terminal keep process
- bash while terminal
- mac terminal loop command
- ffmpeg infinite

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this from the bash prompt:

```
n=1 ; while true ; do echo -n "Command launch #$n: " ; sleep 1 ; n=$(( n + 1 )) ; done
```

Note: You may actually need `sleep 1` in there, to allow for some cleanup before you re-launch.